# Magento Password Reset Link

Tags: magento

We run a multi-store/view magento site. Let's say our site is called **www.domain.com** (running the "retail" store) and another url **trade.domain.com** running the "trade" store

When a customer requests a password reset from **trade.domain.com**, they get a password reset link like this: http://trade.domain.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=12&token=84fb6f65548995191e526b815982bf23

Clicking this link re-directs to login page with the error `Your password reset link has expired.`.

However, if you replace the "trade" from the domain with "www" like this: http://www.domain.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=12&token=84fb6f65548995191e526b815982bf23

The password reset appears to be working correctly.

Any idea why this is happening? Have I configured the magento incorrectly? Is this a known bug?

Comment: which one you think is correct `trade.domain.com` or `domain.com`?

Comment: Both are correct. `domain.com` is running the "**Retail** Store View" and `trade.domain.com` is running the "**Trade** Store View"

Comment: The sub domains acts as two different domains . Have you installed two  seperate magento for `Retail` and `trade`

Comment: No, I have not installed two magento. It's a single install with multi-store/view setup. We use nginx as the web server. On the vhost entry, we have a config for both domain. Each domain runs their respective store view code.

Comment: Are they using different databases? Sounds to me like `trade.domain.com` is looking for the `token` parameter in its own DB, and doesn’t find it – because it has been written into the DB `domain.com` is using …

Comment: No, I am not using two databases. It's a single magento install, multi-store/view setup. Here's my nginx config for both domains: [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=puP5EZnu](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=puP5EZnu). This is how the store looks like in mage backend: [http://i.imgur.com/RYmHnNY.png](http://i.imgur.com/RYmHnNY.png)

Comment: Do you have different locale/timezone in the websites ?

Comment: No I do not. The server, the php and magento config is all pointing to timezone: Europe/London

Answer (score 0):

Customers are shared either per website, either across all websites, so at least, a customer account is usable on all of the store views that a website contains. Consequently, it is normal that the password  reset link works for your store views.

In fact, if you would like to separate the customer accounts between your store views, you would have to create separate websites that would not share customers.

Answer (score 0):

Is that subdomain password protected? That could be a problem or if subdomain is set up with a password protected extension, they won't be able to access example.com/customer/account/changeforgotten/ without already being logged in. So you'll have to allow them access to that url first otherwise it'll keep redirecting. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cookie domain for the website trade.domain.com.  In Magento 1 it's in System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management.  (Making sure that you change the scope in the top left to the Website you want to update it for.

I have a store that has multiple websites, each with their own view and does not share accounts across websites, and had the same problem.  Changing the cookie path fixed it for me.